# Laravel Dingo Api - How to return JSON formatted error response from API Controller?

Tags: php, laravel

In my routes.php, I have this:

```
$apiSettings = [
    'version' => 'v1',
    'prefix' => 'api',
    'protected' => true
];   
Route::api($apiSettings, function() {
    Route::get('venue', 'ApiDataController@venue');
});
```

The protected venue API route accesses a controller method. The controller method performs the Eloquent Query on a Venues model, and returns the response. This works perfectly.
The issue is in if I want to return an error - I am unsure how to. Here is the Venue Method:

```
public function venue(){

    try {
        //Some code that returns an exception
    } catch(someexception $e) {
        //How do I return the exception such that Dingo will parse it into a proper JSON response?
    }
    $response = Venue::with('address')->get();
    return $response;

}
```

My attempted solution (in the try block):

```
try {
    //some code that returns an exception
} catch(someexception $e) {
    $response = array(
        'message' => 'some random exception message'
    );
    return Response::json($response, 403);
}
```

I got the following error when I attempted to do that:
`Argument 1 passed to Dingo\Api\Http\Response::makeFromExisting() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Response, instance of Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse given, called in /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php on line 165 and defined`

Second Attempted Solution:
From Dingo's Returning Errors, docs, I tested what would happen if I returned one of the exceptions:

```
public function venue(){
    throw new Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ConflictHttpException('err);
}
```

However, instead of returning the error as a JSON response, a laravel error page comes up, with the following error displayed:

```
[internal function]: ApiDataController->venue()
#1 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231):
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(93):
Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('venue', Array)
#3 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(62):
Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(ApiDataController),
Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'venue')
#4 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(930):
Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
Object(Dingo\Api\Http\InternalRequest), 'ApiDataControll...', 'venue')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#6 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(105):
call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#7 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996):
Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\InternalRequest))
#8 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(964):
Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\InternalRequest))
#9 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(147):
Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\InternalRequest))
#10 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Dispatcher.php(337): Dingo\Api\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\InternalRequest))
#11 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Dispatcher.php(278): Dingo\Api\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Dingo\Api\Http\InternalRequest))
#12 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Dispatcher.php(213): Dingo\Api\Dispatcher->queueRequest('get', 'venue', Array)
#13 /vagrant/www/planat-app/app/routes.php(51): Dingo\Api\Dispatcher->get('venue')
#14 [internal function]: {closure}()
#15 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(105):
call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#16 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996):
Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(964):
Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(147):
Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(738):
Dingo\Api\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708):
Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/RateLimit.php(97):
Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
1, true)
#22 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Authentication.php(102):
Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\RateLimit->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
1, true)
#23 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72):
Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\Authentication->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
1, true)
#24 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47):
Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
1, true)
#25 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51):
Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
true)
#26 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23):
Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
true)
#27 /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(606):
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /vagrant/www/planat-app/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
```

Comment: In the laravel error page, does it show the same "Argument 1 passed to Dingo\Api\Http\Response::makeFromExisting() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Response" or what does it show? I think it should show a different error now A more copy-pastable error message should be the last chunk in your `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` too.

Comment: I've updated the question with the stack trace from laravel.log

Comment: I think it has to do with syntax error. Can you check that your controller action has correct braces and everything? Or post your controller action code here.

Comment: Would be nice too if you could get the error log two lines above `[internal function]:`

Comment: @Unnawut  why you need to try catch and then response exception message. Dingo Will handle exception and will response exception message automatically. See the following example.                                   
    
     {
         "message": "Undefined variable: x",
         "status_code": 500
     }

Api endpoint have a undefined variable "x" and dingo handle it appropriately

Answer (score 3):

As you are building api, you can catch similar types of exception globally. For example, if a user tried to get a customer with an ID which doesn't exists, then you could do this.

```
Customer::findOrFail($id);
```

then you could catch all of this type exception in `app/start/global.php` like this.

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $modelNotFoundException){
    $errorResponse = [
        'errors'    => 'Not found any resource',
        'message'   => $modelNotFoundException->getMessage()
    ];

    return Response::json($errorResponse, 404);     //404 = Not found
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading from Dingo's [Returning Errors](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Returning-Errors) docs, it says:

> Instead of manually creating and returning an error response you can simply throw an exception and the package will handle the exception and return an appropriate response.
>
> The following is a list of all the supported exceptions that you should throw when you encounter an error.
>
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ConflictHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\GoneHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\LengthRequiredHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotAcceptableHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\PreconditionFailedHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\PreconditionRequiredHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ServiceUnavailableHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\TooManyRequestsHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException

It also supports some generic resource exceptions that you can pass validation errors onto as well:

> Dingo\Api\Exception\DeleteResourceFailedException
> Dingo\Api\Exception\ResourceException
> Dingo\Api\Exception\StoreResourceFailedException
> Dingo\Api\Exception\UpdateResourceFailedException

So in short, you need to throw one of the exceptions above that Dingo supports back to Dingo. For example:

```
try {
    //Some code that returns an exception
} catch(SomeException $e) {
    throw new Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException($e->getMessage);
}
```

Or in fact, if the exception thrown is one of the type above, or one that extends them, you can just remove your try/catch clause completely. The exception should be automatically thrown back to Dingo to handle it.

Comment: Hi Unnawut, thanks for the answer. However, I did try this originally, and I get an exception from it: Argument 1 passed to Dingo\Api\Http\Response::makeFromExisting() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Response, instance of Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse given, called in /vagrant/www/planat-app/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php on line 165 and defined

Comment: I've updated the question to contain my attempted solution (same as the once you've provided), and the error response that I get.

Comment: @Muserk My original answer was totally off. Updated!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I throw any of their specified exceptions, it does not get returned as JSON. Instead, the laravel error page comes up, with the exception message.

Comment: Could you also append your latest code to the question too? In case other people might have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
try {
    //some code that returns an exception
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $response = array(
        'message' => 'some random exception message'
    );
    return response()->json($response, 403);
}
```

Please check and let me know.